# How to make several threads do takes from RabbitMQ queue using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

Our application consumes data from several queues that are provided by RabbitMQ. To increase throughput we start several threads per queue that do blocking takes from those queues.

For a new service we want to use Spring Boot and again have several threads per queue that take data from those queues. Here is the canonical Spring Boot code for processing data that arrived from some queue:

```
@StreamListener(target = Processor.INPUT)
@SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
public Message<SomeData> process(Message<SomeData> message) {
    SomeData result = service.process(message.getPayload());
    return MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(result)
            .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
            .build();
}
```

Question is now how to make Spring Boot spawn several threads to serve one queue instead of a single thread. Throughput is very critical for our application, hence the need for this.

Answer (score 4):

Check the [available properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties), search for rabbitmq.

> spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency= # Minimum number of listener invoker threads

That looks promising

Comment: Thanks, Tomasz. I wonder whether there is a way to set the concurrency for individual queues, e.g. something like spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency.myqueue

Comment: I don't think so, at least not out of the box. I believe in reality listeners do not bind to a queue, but to the broker as a whole, and just say what queues are they interested with (but it's just my wild guess)

Comment: This configuration works well, it enables multiple messages to be consumed even if the first one is still under processing

Answer (score 2):

You can set the concurrent consumers for the queue when you configurate it.

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory
        (MessageConverter contentTypeConverter,
         SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();

    // the number of consumers is set as 5
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(5);

    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(contentTypeConverter);
    return factory;
}
```